# Microsoft Word 2013 (and other softwares) titled line effect?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a question about a titled line effect like so: 
--------------------- Heading ---------------------
but with actual lines. I know Microsoft Word 2013 has the ability to make horizontal lines but I cannot figure out how to center a word in it. I would like to have this effect with a real line, not hyphens like my little example. If anyone could offer some help or recommend a better word processor that has this function, I would be appreciative.

Thanks!

Comment: I googled ms word "horizontal line" with and then google offered with text.  http://superuser.com/questions/88569/how-do-i-get-horizontal-lines-to-the-left-and-right-of-a-heading-in-microsoft-wo     <-- strikethrough space to the left and right of the text    I can't say it works perfectly for me.. but if you have any issue then edit it into your question

Answer (score 1):

You could improvise with 2 tabs.

Set one at the value of the centre of your page as a Centred tab, with _____ leader (option 4).

Then set a Right Aligned tab at your right margin, again with ____ leader (option 4).

Type a tab then your heading text then another tab.

The lines will be too low (as they are underscore), so to correct this you can select the tab character and format the font (on Advanced tab of Font dialog) so that Position is set to Raised by, for example, 4pt (adjust depending on your heading text font size).  Repeat for the tab character following your heading.