# Designing header in Word between horizontal lines

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, styles, headers

I am trying to design something like this in Word.

```
           ---------------------- MY TITLE ----------------------
```

The title would be centered, and the left and right lines would extend equally (automatically) towards the end of the line.

Is it possible? If so, how can it be done? I am using Word 2016 (windows or Mac).

Comment: I found a older post here,: http://superuser.com/questions/88569/how-do-i-get-horizontal-lines-to-the-left-and-right-of-a-heading-in-microsoft-wo, but this does not seem to apply to modern versions of Word. Anyone know how to do this in Word 2016?

Comment: ahh were you looking for heading or a header ? saw your comment now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its already built in Word 2016 (*Windows & Macintosh*)

Go to Insert → Header → Down arrow ↓ → Branded style is what you need and you can customize the color and size too

[image]